# Will In-App purchase work for previous version of app if in-app gets approved for latest ones?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Will In-App purchase work for previous version of app if in-app gets approved for latest ones? I have an app in the app store published which contains all in-app logic and stuff. But the in-app item was not published. So I created a new version and submitted it for in-app review. If the new version gets approved and is available for download, will the users using the previous version of the app automatically be able to use in-app? Currently the app crashes during the in-app purchase flow as the store doesn't return the relevant info.

Comment: Crash in testing or store version? Does the previous version have the product id and associated processing logic?

Comment: Crashes in store version. The previous version gets the product ids from server. So the app will have productId. It crashes because the in-app items was not send to review before the app got published.

Comment: It sounds like it's crashing because the productid isn't being found, and your code doesn't expect that? Did you forget to use SKProductsRequest? That should only return valid productIds that are active. You could try reading out the logs from your device after running the production version to see why it crashes exactly. It should log the productid not found from the AppStore. Anyway, if that's the reason why it's crashing, then it should start working just fine once the IAP is approved I'd say.

Comment: That's good to know. It's crashing because app store does not return any info when `buy(productId)` is called. It works fine in test builds. The last sentence clears my doubt.